# ¿Cómo eliminar o reemplazar todas las subcadenas de un string en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

> De la pregunta del SO original [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Por ejemplo, si tengo una cadena como esta:

```
var str = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
```

y hago:

```
str = str.replace('abc', '');
```

Sólo elimina la primera aparición de `abc`, ¿cómo elimino todas las subcadenas `abc`?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Usa [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) (RegExp) con el parámetro g, búsqueda global

## Fragmento

```js
/**
 * Ejemplo simple
 *
 */
var cadena = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";
var re = /abc/g;
var resultado = cadena.replace(re, '');
console.log(resultado);
```

## Observaciones

Las expresiones regulares no son triviales ya que ciertos caracteres tienen un efecto en la manera que se interpreta la expresión regular. El procesamiento de estas debe aplicarse sólo a cadenas seguras o en su defecto deberían escaparse antes de ser procesadas. A continuación un ejemplo mas completo.

```js
/**
 * Ejemplo simple modificado
 *
 */

// Tomado de 
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); 
}

// Cadena a procesar
var cadena = "Test abc test test abc test test test abc test test abc";

// Simular entrada de usuario
var entradaUsuario = "abc";

// Aplicar la función para escapar la entrada de usuario
var re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(entradaUsuario),'g');

// Aplicar reemplazo
var resultado = cadena.replace(re, '');

// Imprimir en la consola el resultado
console.log(resultado);
```

### Fuente

[Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606289/1595451) a [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

### Véase también

- [Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49210/)

Comment: Me encanta tu respuesta, no usa ni `prototipos` ni `joins`.

Comment: Gracias Gepser. En lo personal encuentro muy útiles las expresiones regulares.

Comment: Detalle: no es necesario escapar `]` ni `}` (está así en MDN, pero está mal). Sin embargo, se deberían escapar los `$` en el reemplazo.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano. Además de mejorar esta respuesta habría que hacer lo mismo con la fuente referida (Mozilla Developer Network). ¿participas ahí también?

Comment: @Rubén llevaría a una discusión de la que no tengo ganas de participar: *qué pasa si un usuario quiere escapar **parte** de un regex y no todo* (en cuyo caso podría necesitar escapar esos caracteres)

Comment: Te preguntaba porque al momento no he participado en MDN como editor. Esperaría que un cambio como el que aquí has sugerido no  fuera a llevar a una discusión como la que comentas, en particular por el propósito que entiendo tiene el ejemplo.

Comment: @Mariano: ¿Que tal si aboradamos esto al estilo SOes? -> [Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49210/forma-segura-de-escapar-entrada-de-usuario-para-ser-procesada-por-expresiones-re)

Answer (score 6):

[String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) acepta como primer parámetro a un string o un objeto [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp).

Si se desea reemplazar todos los `"abc"`, sólo basta con emplear una expresión regular con el modificador [`/g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Parameters) (*global*), que indica que se reemplacen todas las ocurrencias.

```
resultado = str.replace(/abc/g, '');
```

Y si se quiere ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas, se usa el modificador [`/i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Parameters) (*ignore case*):

```
resultado = str.replace(/abc/gi, '');
```

> Sólo se debe tener en cuenta escapar los caracteres especiales, antecediéndolos con `\`. Por ejemplo, para reemplazar `"abc."`, la expresión regular sería `/abc\./g`. Los caracteres especiales son:
>
> ```
> \   ^   $   .   |   ?   *   +   (   )   [   {
> ```
>
> Y en el reemplazo, escapar `$` como `$$`.
>
> Esto está explicado en [*Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49215/127)

---

**Caso general:**

Esto mismo se puede llevar al caso general, para reemplazar cualquier subcadena, y escapando todos los caracteres especiales.

```js
function reemplazarTodos( texto, reemplazarQue, reemplazarCon, ignorarMayMin){
  var reemplazarQue = reemplazarQue.replace(/[\\^$.|?*+()[{]/g, "\\$&"),
      reemplazarCon = reemplazarCon.replace(/\$(?=[$&`'\d])/g, "$$$$"),
      modif = "g" + (ignorarMayMin ? "i" : ""),
      regex = new RegExp(reemplazarQue, modif);
  
  return texto.replace(regex,reemplazarCon);
}


//Prueba
var texto = "--abc.--abc.---abcX---AbC.",
    resultado1 = reemplazarTodos(texto, "abc.", "def"),
    resultado2 = reemplazarTodos(texto, "abc.", "def", true);
console.log(texto, "⟶", resultado1);
console.log(texto, "⟶", resultado2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Extender los prototipos de los tipos originales (`built-in prototype`) no es lo recomendado pero con el fin de mostrar una solución diferente voy a poner un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo modificando el prototipo de `String`.

**Implementación basada en expresiones regulares**

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

**Implementación basada en Split y Join (Funcional)**

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Se usaría así:

```
console.log(cadena.replaceAll("abc"));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Nota: no usar este método en código real**

Una alternativa a las expresiones regulares puede ser:

```
str = "Test abc test test abc test...".split("abc").join("");
```

El patrón general es:

```
str.split(búsqueda).join(reemplazar)
```

Esto solía, en algunos casos, ser más rápido que usar `protoypes` y expresiones regulares pero no parece ser el caso en los exploradores modernos. Por lo anterior esto sólo debería usarse como algo rápido para evitar escapar la  expresión regular pero no para código real que va a ir a producción.

> [Ver la respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145525/2518022)

Comment: No le veo sentido publicar como primer respuesta un método no recomendado, por otro lado, ¿por qué se querría evitar el uso de expresiones regulares cuando se quiere hacer algo rápido?

Comment: @Rubén Sólo estoy traduciendo las respuestas originales más votadas. Esta es una de ellas. La otra está más amplia (y tampoco es recomendado el uso de `prototype`). De hecho, la tuya es la respuesta que aceptaría. Saludos.

Comment: Sirva este caso de ejemplo de que la "sabiduría de las masas" no siempre es sabia, en particular en un sistema como el los sitios de [se] :)

Comment: Había un "pequeño detalle" en la traducción. La respuesta original, en lugar de decir que "evitar usar expresiones regulares" hacía mención de lo que se quería evitar es el tener que escapar la expresión regular. Apliqué la corrección correspondiente, pero de todas formas, pienso que si bien es útil traducir la respuesta original, no debía seleccionarse como la primera con base en el número de votos, hubiera sido mejor, seleccionar otra con base en representar una buena práctica.