# Cuantificador para que coincida con 1 o más caracteres en Expresiones Regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular, la cual me funciona para un subdominio de 2 letras:

```js
var subdomains = [
    "es.stackoverflow.com", // valido
    "ru.stackoverflow.com", // valido
    "12.stackoverflow.com", // invalido
    "30.stackkoverflow.com" // invalido
];

const regex = "\^[a-z]{2}.stackoverflow.com$";

for (var i = 0; i < subdomains.length; i++) {
  console.log((subdomains[i].match(regex)) ? 'valido' : 'invalido');
}
```

Pero quiero que me coincida con **cualquier subdominio de cualquier longitud**, sólo con letras de la a **a** la **z**, nada más.

---

Esto es lo que intenté:

```js
var subdomains = [
    "esssss.stackoverflow.com",    // valido
    "ru.stackoverflow.com",        // valido
    "12.stackoverflow.com",        // invalido
    "30.stackkoverflow.com",       // invalido
    "es.stackoverflow.com",        // valido  
    "subdominio.stackoverflow.com" // valido
];   

const regex = "\^[a-z].stackoverflow.com$";

for (var i = 0; i < subdomains.length; i++) {
    console.log((subdomains[i].match(regex)) ? 'valido' : 'invalido');
}
```

Pero si remuevo la ocurrencia de N carácteres `{2}`, no me funciona bien. ¿Cómo lo puedo corregir?

Comment: @Mariano listo, actualicé mi pregunta*, espero haber sido más claro

Comment: @Mariano, exactamente, cualquier caracter de la **a** *a* la **z**, nada más.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algo para corregir antes de empezar:

- Las expresiones regulares en JavaScript van entre `/`s, sin usar comillas. Eso construye directamente a un objeto [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp).
- No deberías escapar la `^` con una `\` para que coincida con el inicio del texto (va directamente en el regex).
- Los puntos coinciden con cualquier caracter (uno) que no sea un salto de línea, a menos que los escapes. Para que coincida con un punto literal, entonces sí hay que escaparlos como `\.`. Más info de todos los caracteres especiales: [Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/127)
- Para ver sólo si coincide o no, te conviene usar el método [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test).

Entonces, partamos de la expresión:

```
const miRegex = /^[a-z]{2}\.stackoverflow\.com$/;
```

---

#### Cómo cuantificar en regex

Los cuantificadores en expresiones regulares aplican al subpatrón previo. Lo usaste en lo que estás intentando: en `[a-z]{2}`, el `{2}` cuantifica a `[a-z]` (lo repite 2 veces).

Si no se utiliza un cuantificador, como por ejemplo en `/^[a-z]\.stackoverflow\.com$/`, entonces coincide con textos que tengan 1 solo caracter como subdominio.

Lo que estás intentando es que coincida con 1 o más caracteres en el subdominio. Para eso, podríamos utilizar el cuantificador `{1,}` (1 a infinitos) o, lo que es lo mismo, el [cuantificador `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus).

```
/^[a-z]+\.stackoverflow\.com$/
```

#### Código

```js
var subdomains = [
    "esssss.stackoverflow.com",    // valido
    "ru.stackoverflow.com",        // valido
    "12.stackoverflow.com",        // invalido
    "30.stackkoverflow.com",       // invalido
    "es.stackoverflow.com",        // valido  
    "subdominio.stackoverflow.com",// valido
    "ES.stackoverflow.com"         // invalido (mayúsculas)
];   

const regex = /^[a-z]+.stackoverflow.com$/;

for (var i = 0; i < subdomains.length; i++) {
    console.log(subdomains[i], regex.test(subdomains[i]) ? 'valido' : 'invalido');
}
```

#### Otros cuantificadores

```
  Cuant.   Descripción                             
 -------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  ?        1 o 0                                                             
  ??       0 o 1                                                             
  *        infinito a 0                                                      
  *?       0 a infinito                                                      
  +        infinito a 1                                                      
  +?       1 a infinito                                                      
  {n}      exactamente n repeticiones                                      
  {m,n}    hasta n repeticiones, mínimo m                         
  {m,n}?   mínimo m, hasta n repeticiones
  {m,}     entre m e infinitas repeticiones, cuantos más puedan coincidir    
  {m,}?    entre m e infinitas repeticiones, cuantas menos puedan coincidir
  {,n}     entre 0 y n repeticiones (sólo Python y Ruby)
```

**Ejemplos:**

```
  Cuant.    Descripción                             
 --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+       1 o más alfanuméricos (incluye "_"), cuantas más puedan coincidir
  \d{6}     exactamente 6 dígitos consecutivos
  x{3,6}    3 a 6 letras "x" consecutivas, cuantas más puedan coincidir
  @{2,5}?   2 a 5 arrobas consecutivas, cuantas menos puedan coincidir
```

#### Otras opciones para este caso

Alternativamente, si quisieras que también coincida con mayúsculas, usamos el [modificador `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#B%C3%BAsqueda_Avanzada_Con_%27Banderas%27_(Flags)) (CASE INSENSITIVE):

```
/^[a-z]+\.stackoverflow\.com$/i
```

O que coincida, tenga o no un subdominio, podríamos [agrupar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) la primer parte con `(?:`...`)`, y hacerla opcional con el cuantificador `{0,1}`, que es lo mismo que el [cuantificador `?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark).

```
/^(?:[a-z]+\.)?stackoverflow\.com$/i
```

---

**Más recursos**

- Guía para expresiones regulares en JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expression
- *Regular Expressions Tutorial*: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html
- Para probar expresiones online: https://regex101.com/

Comment: mil gracias por tu respuesta, me haz dejado claro muchas cosas, una pregunta, la **i** que estás agregando al final de la expresión, ¿para que es?

Comment: @Jorius ah, lo había escrito en orden y luego lo moví para abajo. El modificador `/i` ignora mayúsculas/minúsculas, haciendo que `[a-z]` también coincida con una `"E"`