# Validación de código postal español con expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

Estoy haciendo una validación de códigos postales españoles. Los requisitos son

- que tenga 5 dígitos, y
- que los números estén comprendidos entre 01000 y 52999.

He conseguido validarlo con la siguiente expresión regular, pero me parece muy larga y no sé si hay forma de mejorarla. La expresión es:

```
/(([1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|(0(?=[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]))|(5(?=[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])))/
```

Se me ocurre que en todas las variaciones, los tres últimos valores son del 0 al 9 `[0-9]` y no encuentro si hay manera de unificarlo y no escribir tanto código.

¿Hay alguna manera de acortar o mejorar la expresión?

Comment: El cero a la izquierda es obligatorio?

Comment: No estoy  seguro de ello, así que he dado por hecho que si lo es.

Comment: Si no fuera por el requisito de mínimo y máximo, sería tan corto como `^\d{5}$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Una expresión regular puede coincidir en cualquier lugar del texto, a menos que agregues condiciones. Por ejemplo, englobando entre `^` y `$`, que coinciden con el inicio y el final del texto respectivamente.
- `\d` es lo mismo que `[0-9]`.
  (vale en JavaScript, en otros lenguajes puede coincidir con dígitos de otros alfabetos en Unicode)
- No sé por qué estás usando inspecciones positivas `(?=`...`)` (o *lookaheads*), no le veo el sentido.
- Existen [cuantificadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers) que te permiten repetir la construcción previa. `\d\d\d\d` es lo mismo que `\d{4}`. Te recomiendo leer la pregunta *[Cuantificador para que coincida con 1 o más caracteres en Expresiones Regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64522/127)*.

En definitiva, no hay una mejor forma de escribirla que cubriendo todos los casos, pero se puede acortar un poco con estos puntos que mencioné.

Número entre 01000 y 52999:

```
/^(?:0[1-9]\d{3}|[1-4]\d{4}|5[0-2]\d{3})$/
```

O, lo que es lo mismo:

```
/^(?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-2])\d{3}$/
```

> Nota: no sabemos si el cero a la izquierda en números menores a 10000 es opcional. Si lo fuese,
>
> ```
> /^(?:0?[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-2])\d{3}$/
> ```

---

> <sup>Para ver rangos numéricos, muchas veces es más sencillo/práctico/más fácil de mantener si se utilizan las herramientas intrínsecas de cada lenguaje, simplemente viendo si el número es mayor/menor que el rango. A lo sumo, coincidiendo con `/^\d{4,5}$/` y comparando luego.</sup>

Comment: Gracias Mariano. Puede ser que no estuviera utilizando bien los lookahead por no entenderlos muy bien, pero no me di cuenta hasta ahora porque no afectaba a la expresión final que buscaba, ya que la precedia de un condicional en mi script.

Comment: Si te interesa entenderlos y te animás a leer en inglés, te recomiendo https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Gracias le echaré un vistazo.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas expresiones regulares para hacer algo tan simple. Simplemente valida si el codigo postal tiene mas de 5 caracteres utilizando `length` y luego pregunta si el valor mayor a 01000 y menor a 52999 .

Ejemplo:

```js
function validarCodigoPostal()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
  console.log(parseInt(input))
  if(input.length == 5 && parseInt(input) >= 1000 && parseInt(input) <= 52999)
  {
    alert("codigo valido");
  }
  else{
    alert("codigo invalido");
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="codigo" />
<button onclick="validarCodigoPostal()">validar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero estoy practicando con las expresiones regulares y por eso el hacerlo de esa manera. ¿Sabes si hay manera de acortarla?

Answer (score -1):

Con eso puedes validar un código postal:

```
^[0-5][1-9]{3}[0-9]$
```