# ¿Cómo validar la entrada de datos con expresiones regulares en un input que permita solo números?

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Necesitaría saber como validar un `input` de un formulario con expresiones regulares que debe de contener obligatoriamente 6 números.

Hasta ahora no lo he conseguido, les dejo el código.

```
if (document.formCliente.numeroContabilidad.value!="") {

  var regNUM = /^ ([0-9]) *$/;

  if (regNUM.test(document.formCliente.numeroContabilidad.value) == false){
      alert("El numero de contabilidad es incorrecto.");
      document.formCliente.numeroContabilidad.focus();
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inicio del texto, un número repetido 6 veces, fin del texto

```
/^[0-9]{6}$/
```

Que es lo mismo que:

```
/^\d{6}$/
```

> `x{6}` es un [cuantificador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier). Para ver más detalles, podés leer: [Cuantificador para que coincida con 1 o más caracteres en Expresiones Regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64522/127)

---

Y si se quiere evitar que empiece por cero, buscamos que coincida con un dígito del 1 al 9, seguido de 5 dígitos más:

```
/^[1-9]\d{5}$/
```

---

Alternativamente, en HTML5 se puede dejar la validación al navegador:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[1-9]\d{5}">
```

- Al usar el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input#attr-pattern), siempre está anclado a `^` y `$`, por lo que no hace falta agregarlo al regex.
- Todos los navegadores modernos lo soportan ([ver tabla](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern)).