# Como validar si un string contiene solo numeros?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quiero validar si un string contiene solo numeros, busque mucho y hasta intente usar jQuery pero tengo problemas instalandolo con node, si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: NodeJS y JQuery, no entiendo el tipo de *investigación* realizada (*busqué mucho*) es lo que pones en tu pregunta. Una simple búsqueda en este mismo sitio usando: `validar numeros [javascript]` te arroja varias respuestas que podrían haberte orientado. Cuando tengas un verdadero problema, con un [mcve] que indique que has intentado *hacer* algo, eres bienvenido a realizar la pregunta sobre dicho problema. De lo contrario, me temo que tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías usar una [expresión regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) (*regex*).

```
const regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
const onlyNumbers = regex.test(`34563`); // true
```

En Javascript, las *regex* se declaran entre slashes (`/`).
`^` marca el comienzo de la cadena.
`$` marca el final de la cadena.
`[0-9]` indica un caracter numérico.
`*` indica que se cumpla 0 o más veces.

La función `test` de una *regex* aplica la expresión a un `string` por parámetro y devuelve `true` o `false`, si cumple o no.

Las *regex* son todo un mundo, deberías leer acerca de ellas y [practicarlas](https://regexr.com/).

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Por favor, quien puntúe mal las respuestas que escriba un comentario justificando el por qué. Así mejoramos todxs...

Comment: +1 porque es util tu respuesta, sin embargo la pregunta esta mal formulada... normalmente no se responde a las preguntas mal formuladas o que no contienen ningún código tener en cuenta esto, no es que este deacuerdo con ello, pero la mayoría de respuestas que responden a preguntas así normalmente aunque sean útiles terminan teniendo votos negativos solo porque la pregunta en teoría no debería ser respondida (me ha pasado y odio cuando pasa), la comunidad debería tener en cuenta las buenas respuestas a preguntas mal formuladas (si son útiles como en este caso).

Comment: Por norma general, **yo** no respondo preguntas de esta naturaleza, porque fomenta el mal hábito de usuarios nuevos que no han investigado absolutamente nada y pretenden que les solucionen el problema. Tu respuesta es buena, pero incluso ya han respondido lo mismo [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133015/c%c3%b3mo-validar-la-entrada-de-datos-con-expresiones-regulares-en-un-input-que-perm), por ejemplo. No puedes evitar que la comunidad vote negativo si consideran que tu respuesta no aporta nada adicional. Antes de responder verifica que no exista ya una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones a ambos. En efecto, entiendo los puntos. Mi comentario se debe a que un voto negativo no aporta nada si no se justifica. Me ayudan muchísimo más vuestros comentarios que un voto negativo, que no me dice nada. De todas formas, gracias de nuevo. Procuraré ser más crítico a la hora de responder preguntas.