# Expresión regular que haga match cuando no se repitan dígitos

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero que sólo de match si la longitud es <= 10

Por ejemplo:

```
113456789 false ya que se repite el "1"
123456789 true no se repite ninguno
365728391 false ya que se repite el "3"
237810564 true no se repite ninguno
```

he intentando con esta expresion regular :

```
"^\d{1}((\d{1}){1,9})?$"
```

pero me sigue dando true aun cuando se repiten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenemos 2 condiciones. La primera, que sean entre 0 y 10 dígitos, basta con repetir a `\d` (con un [cuantificador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64531/127)) entre 0 y 10:

```
^\d{0,10}$
```

Para ver que un dígito no se repite, tenemos que empezar al revés, intentando que coincida con un mismo dígito 2 veces. Para eso usamos un grupo (entre paréntesis), y luego intentamos que coincida con el texto capturado por ese grupo con `\1` (una [retrorreferencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches), o *[backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)*).

```
(\d).*\1
```

- El `.*` permite que haya cualquier cantidad de caracteres entre el primer dígito capturado por el grupo 1, y la referencia de `\1`.

Y para negar esta parte, usamos una [inspección negativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead) (o *[negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*) desde el inicio del texto, cuya sintaxis es `(?!`…`)`, para ver que *no esté seguido por*:

```
^(?!.*(\d).*\1)
```

Como una inspección no consume caracteres (no mueve el puntero de posición principal), luego de ver que no esté seguida por `^(?!.*(\d).*\1)`, podemos intentar la primera condición, ya que sigue estando en la posición 0 del string. Combinamos a ambos patrones en el mismo regex.

**Regex:**

```
^(?!.*(\d).*\1)\d{0,10}$
```

Código:

```
var re = /^(?!.*(\d).*\1)\d{0,10}$/;

if ( ! re.test( texto ) ) {
    //clave inválida
}
```

---

Demo:

```js
let pruebas = [
        113456789,
        123456789,
        365728391,
        237810564,
        1234565789
    ],
    re = /^(?!.*(\d).*\1)\d{0,10}$/;
    
for (let prueba of pruebas) {
    let resultado = re.test(prueba);
    console.log(prueba, resultado);
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderCh en la [información de la etiqueta regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), hay algunos enlaces a tutoriales... Si te animás a leer en inglés, te recomiendo https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html