# ¿Por qué el combobox que tengo vinculado a SQL muestra el símbolo ¶ (salto de párrafo), y cómo quitarlo?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, combobox

Estoy programando un formulario en Excel / VBA que obtiene datos de una tabla en SQL SERVER, dicho formulario tiene varios Comboboxes que obtienen sus datos de diversas tablas, el problema es que en particular 2 de ellos me muestran el símbolo ¶ (salto de párrafo) en cada fila del combobox pero no encuentro la razón (si el error está en el código o en la tabla de SQL SERVER); el código es el mismo para todos los comboboxes, pero sólo dos tienen este problema. ¿qué puedo hacer para que lo deje de mostrar? Dejo un ejemplo del código, el primero es el que muestra el símbolo en cuestión y el de abajo es de otro combobox que no tiene ese problema:

Antes, vale decir que cuando ejecuto el form principal se crea la conexión:

```
Sub SQLconnection()
Dim ESTADO
    provStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=***;Persist Security Info=True;" & _
            "User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=pruebaEDGE;Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
cn.connectionstring = provStr
cn.Open
    If cn.State = 1 Then
    ESTADO = MsgBox("Conectado", vbOKOnly, "Estado de Conexión con el Servidor")
    Else: ESTADO = MsgBox("Hubo un error", vbOKOnly, "Estado de Conexión con el Servidor")
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: Símbolos entre lineas]

su código:

```
Sub Llenarprof(ByVal cb As ComboBox)

PROF = "SELECT*FROM [tabla]"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset") 

rs.Open PROF, cn

If Not rs.EOF Then

i = 0

Do Until rs.EOF

cb.AddItem rs.Fields("nombre"), i

i = i + 1

rs.movenext

Loop

End If

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

y este es el caso donde no muestra el símbolo[image: No hay símbolos]

y su código:

```
Sub LlenarActMerc(ByVal cb As ComboBox)

ACTIVIDAD = "SELECT*FROM [tabla]"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

rs.Open ACTIVIDAD, cn

If Not rs.EOF Then

i = 0

Do Until rs.EOF

cb.AddItem rs.Fields("nombre"), i

i = i + 1

rs.movenext

Loop

End If

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Tanto los campos "ocupación" como "giro mercantil" son nvarchar, el primero (50) y el segundo (255). No estoy seguro de cómo se alimentaron estas, pero otro de los comboboxes con el mismo problema se alimenta de una tabla que sí creé a mano.

Comment: Sí , los formularios están hechos en VBA para EXCEL. No entiendo a qué te refieres con los datos de origen. Es una tabla de SQL que tiene  tal cuales esos datos que despliega el combobox, ni un símbolo más ni uno menos, el hecho esta en que las filas de la tabla de SQL SERVER no tienen ese símbolo, únicamente aparecen cuando despliego el combobox al ejecutar el form

Comment: ¿Crees que se deba a que en SQL, la columna esté declarada como char(80) y no se ocupen los 80 caracteres?

Comment: Sí es la misma BD, distintas tablas. Ya agregué el resto del código de la conexión, pero he trabajado con esa función para otros combobox y no tienen ese problema, lo único que encuentro es que la tabla de SQL genere el símbolo por no utilizar el largo de la cadena establecido, pero no sé si sea eso.

Comment: Tanto "ocupación" como "giro mercantil" son nvarchar, el primero (50) y el segundo (255). No estoy seguro de cómo se alimentaron estas, pero otro de los comboboxes con el mismo problema se alimenta de una tabla que sí creé a mano.

Comment: Veo que has aceptado la respuesta. Me da mucho gusto que te haya sido útil. He pasado algunos datos que proporcionaste a través de comentarios a la pregunta ya que los comentarios son para notas provisionales, como post-its, que eventualmente deberían ser eliminados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El [calderón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calder%C3%B3n_(tipograf%C3%ADa)), ¶, (en inglés pilcrow) también llamado "marca de párrafo" puede ser simplemente un carácter más, posiblemente insertado involuntariamente al transferir datos de una forma de almacenamiento a otra. En algunos casos se trata de un salto de línea / retorno de carro (en inglés carriage return), que en una celda de Excel se puede insertar pulsando <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Intro</kbd> o con `CHR(13)`.

Lo primero es verificar si los datos de origen incluyen el salto de línea u otros caracteres "invisibles".

De ser así, deberás valorar las implicaciones de depurar los datos de origen y mientras tanto, o en caso de que no sea posible, eliminar el o los caracteres  antes de pasarlos al combobox,

Si sólo se tratara de un caracter al final, podrías usar cambiar

```
cb.AddItem rs.Fields("nombre"), i
```

por

```
cb.AddItem LEFT(rs.Fields("nombre"),LEN(rs.Fields("nombre")) - 1), i
```

o algo equivalente

---

**Formas de identificar si hay caracteres invisibles**

Una forma muy básica, en caso de que se traten de pocos datos, es importando los datos a una columna en Excel y midiendo la longitud con `LEN()` (creo que en español es `LARGO()`). También se puede intentar usando comparar la longitud del dato con con uno "recortado" usando `TRIM()`.

Una forma intermedia, es usar expresiones regulares para eliminar cualquier carácter que no corresponda a los caracteres válidos. Tal vez algo como

```
[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüUñÑ\-\(\)\,]
```

> Véase [Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/65)

Técnicas más avanzadas implican el uso de herramientas como Notepad++ y OpenRefine y algunas requieren familiarizarse, al menos un poco con la codificación de textos (encoding) y la codificación predeterminada del sistema operativo utilizado así como de las bases de datos implicadas.

Comment: encontré que puede deberse a cómo fue transferida la data a SQL. Seguí una sugerencia que decía que exportara los datos de SQL a texto plano, y ahí quitar los caracteres sobrantes, esto logró quitar el calderón de mi combobox. pero al guardar el txt editado (codificado en UFT-8)y lo importo de vuelta a SQL los acentos ya no los reconoce...en cuanto a tu solución, el problema que encuentro es que algunas filas tienen hasta 3 espacios después de la última letra (lo vi cuando exporté a .txt), es decir los caracteres sobrantes varían, ¿tienes alguna idea de cómo podría agilizar la sustitución?

Comment: @EdgardHuerta: Si, tengo varias. Para casos complejos habría que utilizar una herramienta como OpenRefine, una alternativa es intentar con  alguna herramienta como Notepad++. Te sugiero publicar una nueva pregunta en la que incluyas algunos datos que nos permitan saber que tan complejo es el problema.

Comment: @EdgardHuerta: Hice unos ajustes a la respuesta.