# Como eliminar corchetes con regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Aquí se eliminan palabras "*prohibidas*", pero si esa palabra tiene corchetes, no elimina los corchetes. ¿Qué debo hacer?

```js
var palabrasProhibidas = ['palabra-vulgar','[palabra-vulgar]'];
        var numeroPalabrasProhibidas = palabrasProhibidas.length;
        
        var text = prompt('QUE QUIERES DIBUJAR?','');
        
        while(numeroPalabrasProhibidas--) {
           if (text.indexOf(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas])!=-1) {
               text = text.replace(new RegExp(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas], 'ig'), "");
           }
        }
        
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Porque los corchetes son **metacaracteres** (caracteres especiales) de una expresión regular, y es necesario escaparlos como `'\\[blah\\]'`, o usar una función como **[escaparRegex(string)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/127)**.

Comment: Favor de evitar el uso de palabras vulgares en las publicaciones en este sitio. Referencia [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

¿Por qué estas utilizando regexp?
También agregue una comprobación en el while, por favor prueba el código.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
var palabrasProhibidas = ['palabra-vulgar','[palabra-vulgar]'];
        var numeroPalabrasProhibidas = palabrasProhibidas.length;
        
        var text = prompt('QUE QUIERES DIBUJAR?','');
        
        while(numeroPalabrasProhibidas-- && text!=null) {
   console.log(text.indexOf(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas]));
           if (text.indexOf(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas])!=-1) {
               text = text.replace(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas], "");
           }
        }
        console.log(text);
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
        </script>
```

Comment: no sirve en absoluto

Comment: A mi me funciona perfectamente, prueba haciendo click en ejecutar, ¿necesitas usar el regexp? Brinda mas información por favor

Comment: que me oculte cuando coloco [algo] entre corchetes

Comment: ya esta, fue error mio gracias y disculpa las molestias

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre cuando la palabra prohibida se encuentra repetida más de una vez en el texto?

Comment: Favor de evitar el uso de palabras vulgares en las publicaciones en este sitio. Referencia [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)