# Nothing to repeat error

Tags: javascript, regex

Este código lo que hace *es encontrar en una string* los indices de `"["` y `"]"` , luego con substring, solo tomo la parte dentro de los corchetes.

Luego los dibujo en un `canvas` según el if:

- una string que esta sin el contenido de los corchetes (incluyendo también la eliminación de los corchetes en sí),
- y otra en donde solo se muestra el contenido de los corchetes.

Y todo normal, pero aveces, muy pocas veces, **inesperadamente** me surge el error:

> Nothing to repeat error

**¿Por qué sucede esto?**

```
var b = this.name.indexOf("["); // Busca el [
var c = this.name.indexOf("]"); // Busca el ]
var mostrar = this.name.substring(b, c + 1);
mostrar = mostrar.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
var d = c - b;


if(d > 1 && nameDraw && mostrar != '') {
    var t = this.name.replace(new RegExp(mostrar, 'g'), '');
    t = t.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
    drawText(this.x - 4, this.y, t, this._nameSize, false);
    drawText(this.x, this.y - 62, mostrar, this._nameSize, false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nothing to repeat** es un error de sintaxis dentro de tu expresión regular. Significa que hay un cuantificador (`*`, `?`, `+`, `{m,n}`) que está en una posición donde no tiene nada para repetir. Normalmente sucede con un cuantificador al inicio de la expresión, o con un cuantificador a continuación de otro (inválido).

> Es común verlo cuando no se está escapando correctamente un caracter especial para la expresión regular.

```js
/*  Ejemplo  */
var regex = /abc++?/; //El segundo + no está repitiendo nada!!!
```

---

**Para tu caso** en concreto, sucede porque estás generando un regex dinámicamente a partir de un texto sin escapar los caracteres especiales. Cuando el usuario ingresa algo como por ejemplo `this.name="Genera [error???]"`, estás intentando generar un regex con `"error???"`, que es una expresión inválida.

Para generar un regex literal a partir de un string, se tiene que escapar usando esta función

```
function escaparRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[\\^$.|?*+()[{]/g, '\\$&'); 
}
```

- Más información en: [Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/127)

**Código**

Olvidémonos del problema de escapar el texto, simplifiquemos.

Vamos a usar el regex `/\[([^\]]*)\]/`.

- `\[` - corchete literal.
- `(`...`)` - Grupo capturador. Genera una referencia con el texto con el que coincidió.
  Coincide con:

  - `[^\]]*` - Un caracter, cualquiera excepto `']'`, repetido (`*`) 0 o más veces.
    Es decir, "*coincide con todos los caracteres que no sean `]`*".
- `\]` - corchete literal.

En el [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@replace), en vez de pasar un string, podemos pasar a una función anónima que va a ser llamada para evaluar el reemplazo del regex.

```js
function entreCorchetes (texto) {
    var regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]/,
        resultado;
    
    resultado = texto.replace(regex, function(m, mostrar) {
        if (mostrar !== '') { //si tiene texto
            //Y acá llamarías a drawText
            console.log('Entre corchetes:', mostrar);
        }
        return ''; //reemplazamos por "" (eliminamos)
    });
    
    return resultado;
}



// EJEMPLO

var original = "Prueba [abc+++]";
console.log("Original:", original);

var final = entreCorchetes(original); //llamamos a la función (elimina el primer texto entre corchetes que encuentre)
console.log("Final:", final);
```

**La función anónima** recibe como parámetros el string con el que coincidió el regex, y luego un parámetro por cada captura realizada por cada grupo.

En el regex `/\[([^\]]*)\]/` usamos 1 juego de paréntesis, para capturar el texto que está dentro de los corchetes. Es decir que la función va a recibir como primer parámetro (`m`) el texto con corchetes, y como segundo parámetro (`mostrar`) el mismo texto, pero sin los corchetes.

El resultado de la función es lo que se utilizará efectivamente en el reemplazo del string. Por eso es que devolvemos siempre `''` (texto vacío), para que se eliminen los corchetes del string original. Es lo mismo que hacer, `texto.replace( regex, '');`, pero evaluando la coincidencia en la función.

---

> **¿Y si probamos con algo más sencillo?**
>
> En estas cuestiones, yo siempre me pregunto si no conviene simplificar todo y usar funciones clásicas de manejo de strings. ¿Para qué empezar con revueltas de regex y funciones anónimas anidadas? ¿Está de moda? ¿Parece más "pro"? ¿Cuántas líneas nos ahorramos?
>
> Lo único que estás buscando es:
>
> 1. Obtener la primera ocurrencia de un texto entre corchetes (imprimirla sin corchetes).
> 2. Eliminar esa ocurrencia del string, eliminando también los corchetes (imprimirla).
>
> Paso a paso, con comentarios en el código:
>
> ```js
>  
> //Usemos un ejemplo
> var name = 'Mariano] [clan][no eliminar]';
> //Las variables para el resultado
> var texto,
>     mostrar = "";
>
>
> //Busquemos el primer "["
> var posInicial = name.indexOf('[');
>
> if (posInicial >= 0) { //Encontramos un "["
>
>     //Ahora buscamos la posición de un "]" DESDE la anterior
>     var posFinal = name.indexOf(']', posInicial + 1);
>     
>     if (posFinal >= 0) { //Encontramos un "]"
>     
>         //Obtenemos el clan
>         mostrar = name.substring(posInicial + 1, posFinal);
>         
>         //Obtenemos el texto sin los primeros corchetes
>         // (del inicio hasta antes del que abre + despues del que cierra hasta el final)
>         texto = name.substr(0, posInicial) + name.substr(posFinal + 1);
>     
>     } else { //No tiene ningún "]" luego del "["
>         //Creo que acá no harías nada, no sé, fijate
>         texto = name;
>     }
>     
> } else { //No tiene ningún "["
>     //Creo que acá no harías nada, no sé, fijate
>     texto = name;
> }
>
>
> //Mostremos el resultado
> console.log("Original:", name);
> console.log("Posiciones:", posInicial, posFinal);
> console.log("Final:", texto);
> console.log("Clan:", mostrar);
> ```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61327/discussion-between-mariano-and-eduardo-sebastian).