# ¿Qué significa la expresión regular /\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/?

Tags: javascript, regex

La encontré, y me dio la duda de qué significa esto:

```
var a = str.match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/);
```

Lo que entiendo:

- Match devolverá la coincidencia de la expresión regular
- `\d` significa [0-9]
- El `+` no entiendo que significa muy bien creo que sería como hacer `{1,}` (repetir 1 veces o más), pero realmente no entiendo muy bien como funciona.
- `\b` es principio o fin de la palabra, pero no entiendo como funciona correctamente
- `?=` Ni idea
- `\w` es cualquier alfanumérico `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Entonces resumiendo de todo esto, según lo que entiendo del patrón es:

Se buscara cualquier dígito que se pueda repetir 1 o más veces y después puede venir cualquier cosa `.` <- **(metacaracter)** , y después otro dígito cualquiera que puede repetirse **O** un dígito que puede repetirse 1 o mas veces al final de la string **O** un dígito y no entiendo que más hace después.

Por favor corríjanme. Intento aprender el maravilloso mundo de las expresiones regulares.

Comment: La verdad, este regex no tiene mucho sentido. Hasta es un poco contradictorio en su lógica. Yo no lo usaría.

Comment: La expresion /d+\b/ implica que se busque un numero entero al final de una cadena de caracteres de palabra.

Answer (score 5):

> Nota: Esta respuesta apunta a explicar los conceptos de la expresión regular, pero no recomiendo utilizar el patrón de esta pregunta. No tiene mucho sentido, y hasta es algo contradictorio en cómo está escrito.

#### Conceptos a tener en cuenta

**Una barra antes de un metacaracter hace que pierda su significado especial.** Una barra sirve para [escapar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/127) a un caracter especial. Si bien un punto (`.`) coincide con cualquier caracter excepto saltos de línea, si queremos hacer que coincida con un punto literal, lo escapamos precediéndolo con una barra. Los [metacaracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Utilizando_caracteres_especiales) (o caracteres especiales) son exclusivamente:

```
\   ^   $   .   |   ?   *   +   (   )   [   {
```

Y cuando se quiere hacer coincidir con el caracter literal, se usa una `\`.
Así, `\.` coincide con `"."`.

**El `+` es un cuantificador.** Y como todo [cuantificador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus), sirve para repetir la estructura anterior. El `+` repite la estructura anterior 1 o más veces. Los cuantificadores en expresiones regulares son:

```
  Cuant.   Descripción                             
 -------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  ?        1 o 0                                                             
  ??       0 o 1                                                             
  *        infinito a 0                                                      
  *?       0 a infinito                                                      
  +        infinito a 1                                                      
  +?       1 a infinito                                                      
  {n}      exactamente n repeticiones                                      
  {m,n}    hasta n repeticiones, mínimo m                         
  {m,n}?   mínimo m, hasta n repeticiones
  {m,}     entre m e infinitas repeticiones, cuantos más puedan coincidir    
  {m,}?    entre m e infinitas repeticiones, cuantas menos puedan coincidir
  {,n}     entre 0 y n repeticiones (sólo Python y Ruby)
```

Ejemplos:

```
  Cuant.    Descripción                             
 --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+       1 o más alfanuméricos (incluye "_"), cuantos más puedan coincidir
  ¡(ja){3}! coincide con el texto "¡jajaja!"
  x{3,6}    3 a 6 letras "x" consecutivas, cuantas más puedan coincidir
  @{2,5}?   2 a 5 arrobas consecutivas, cuantas menos puedan coincidir
```

En tu expresión, `\d+\.\d+` coincide con un número con decimales, por ejemplo: `1234.5`, `21.0`, `5.43210`, etc. Es 1 o más dígitos (`\d+`), seguido de un punto (`\.`), seguido de 1 o más dígitos (`\d+`).

**`\b` es un límite de palabra completa.** Es una aserción y, como tal, no coincide con un caracter sino con *una posición*. Se llama [límite de palabra completa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) porque coincide en una posición donde a un lado tenga un caracter de palabra (`\w`, que es lo mismo que `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) y al otro lado no tenga un caracter de palabra (`\W` -que en mayúscula es lo opuesto-, o el inicio o fin del texto).

Técnicamente, `\b` concide en el medio de estos 4 casos: `\w\W`, `\W\w`, `^\w` o `\w$`. En la práctica, nos permite que una expresión como `/\bola\b/` coincida con un `"una ola gigante"` o con `¡surfeamos esa ola!"` y al mismo tiempo que no coincida con `"hola Manola, ¿estás sola?"`.
<sub>-Dejo otras palabras para la imaginación del lector :)</sub>

**`(?=patrón)` es una inspección positiva** (o *[positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*). En castellano, significa que *"está seguido por"*. Una [inspección positiva](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)  `(?=`...`)` intenta una coincidencia con el patrón de la misma y, si coincide, vuelve a la posición en la que se encontraba antes de intentarlo. Es decir, no consume caracteres. Obviamente si no coincide, falla el intento actual.

Como no consume caracteres, coincide con la posición, y no con los caracteres en sí. En tu regex, `\d+(?=\w)` coincide con dígitos que estén seguidos por un caracter de palabra, pero no incluye a ese caracter dentro del resultado.

---

#### Explicación de `/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/`

Son 3 alternativas:

1. `\d+\.\d+` - Un número con decimales.
2. `\d+\b` - Un entero que no está seguido por un caracter de palabra.
3. `\d+(?=\w)` - Un entero que está seguido por un caracter de palabra.

Aparentemente, está intentando coincidir con números con o sin decimales. Sin embargo, quien la haya escrito se hizo algún lío. Es algo incoherente cómo está escrita. ¿Para qué las alternativas 2 y 3 al mismo tiempo? Ni idea.

Es bastante más sencillo y coherente utilizar esta expresión para un número con o sin decimales:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/
```

- `\d+` - 1 o más dígitos.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Es un grupo. `(?:`...`)` se diferencia de un paréntesis normal en que no utiliza memoria extra para capturar lo que haya coincidido con los paréntesis. El `?` al final hace que todo el grupo sea opcional. Así, `\.\d+` coincide con la parte decimal, sólo si existe.

Comment: Siempre voy a admirar la manera tan elegante que tienes de explicar sobre RegEx. Un abrazo hermano :D

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx! Todo un halago viniendo del maestro de los maestros de .Net... Ya volveré a andar por estos pagos más frecuentemente.

Comment: de nada hermano :D gracias por el halago aunque no es para tanto, sigo siendo estudiante, hay mucho por aprender :)