# Consulta que contenga todas las palabras de búsqueda en MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb

Necesito ayuda para realizar unas consultas en MongoDB. Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    var x = ["Esta", "es", "la", "consulta"],
        regex = x.join("|")

    db.coleccion.find({
         campo:{
             "$regex" = regex,
             "$options" = "i"}});
```

Esta consulta me devuelve todos los documentos que contengan por lo menos una palabra de la consulta, pero lo que yo quiero hacer es que me devuelva solo las consultas que contengan **todas** las palabras.

Comment: Si hubieses etiquetado como [tag:regex] desde el comienzo, hubiese visto y respondido a la pregunta ese mismo día.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Buscar una palabra**

Para empezar, no estás buscando las *palabras*, sino cualquier texto que contenga cualquiera de esos strings. El regex `Esta` también coincide con el texto `"Estación"`. Para evitarlo, se utilizan **límites de palabra completa** (**`\b`**), que coinciden en una *posición* entre un caracter de palabra (`[0-9_A-Za-z]`) y uno que no es de palabra.

Entonces, en vez de buscar `Esta`, vamos a buscar:

```
\bEsta\b
```

O, si fuesen múltiples términos, agrupándolos como:

```
\b(?:Esta|es|la|consulta)\b
```

> Tener en cuenta que las letras con diacríticos no son considerados como *caracteres de palabra*, pero para simplificar estoy evitando ese tema.

**2. Buscar que contenga *todos* los términos**

Como ya viste, `patrón1|patrón2|patrón3` encuentra las coincidencias en *cualquiera* de los subpatrones. Para que coincida con *todos* los subpatrones, es un poco más complicado (no mucho). El tema es que el motor de regex recorre el string 1 sola vez, consumiendo los caracteres de izquierda a derecha, y continuando con la siguiente coincidencia desde esa posición.

Para forzar que se consuma desde el inicio más de 1 vez (una vez por cada término), es necesario utilizar inspecciones positivas (*positive lookaheads*), cuya sintaxis es `(?=.*patrón1)`. Esta estructura intenta coincidir con el subpatrón y, luego de la coincidencia, hace que la posición actual vuelva a donde estaba antes de intentar la inspección (obviamente la coincidencia global falla si no coincide la inspección). De esa forma, podemos recorrer los mismos caracteres más de una vez (sin consumirlos).

La expresión quedaría:

```
^(?=.*patrón1)(?=.*patrón2)(?=.*patrón3)(?=.*patrón4)
```

Aunque, para el último término, no es necesario usar una inspección, podemos consumir los caracteres ahí:

```
^(?=.*patrón1)(?=.*patrón2)(?=.*patrón3).*patrón4
```

Pero es indistinto. Tiene un impacto apenas relevante en el rendimiento, pero no lo vamos a usar para facilitar el código.

Entonces, adaptándolo a tu ejemplo:

```
^(?=.*\bEsta\b)(?=.*\bes\b)(?=.*\bla\b)(?=.*\bconsulta\b)
```

**3. Escapar caracteres especiales.**

En tu código estás incluyendo caracteres como literales dentro de la expresión regular. Si pudiese haber un metacaracter dentro de los términos de búsqueda, deberías escaparlos con una barra. Por ejemplo, si se ingresa un `.` un `+`, un `[`, etc. deberías convertirlos a `\.`, `\+`, `\[`, antes de pasarlos.

Para escapar los metacaracteres, podés ver el código en [Forma segura de escapar entrada de usuario para ser procesada por expresiones regulares en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/127).

**4. Permitir saltos de línea en el string.**

En el regex de recién utilizamos `.*`. Un punto coincide con cualquier caracter excepto saltos de línea (algo que muchos se olvidan). Para que un punto también coincida con `\n` y realmente coincida con *cualquier* caracter, hay que usar el modificador `s` (*singleline*).

```
campo:{
    "$regex" = regex,
    "$options" = "is"
}
```

---

#### Código

```
var x = ["Esta", "es", "la", "consulta"],
    regex = "^(?=.*\\b" + x.join("\\b)(?=.*\\b") + "\\b)"

db.coleccion.find({
    campo:{
         "$regex" = regex,
         "$options" = "is"
    }
});
```