# Cambiar color de elementos css dinámicamente con evento y mantenerlo en la hoja de estilos

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Tengo un color-picker que me indica el color hexadecimal que he seleccionado, necesito que ese color, reemplace todo lo que yo tenga en mi hoja de estilos, con color rojo (red).

No importa si lo deja quemado como un element style dentro del HTML, solo necesito que resetee ese color según la selección

Muy agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme

https://codepen.io/andres3dmd/pen/VXaKMX

```js
function update(e){document.getElementById("rect").style.backgroundColor="#"+e}window.jscolor||(window.jscolor=function(){var e,t,n,o,r,i,s={register:function(){s.attachDOMReadyEvent(s.init),s.attachEvent(document,"mousedown",s.onDocumentMouseDown),s.attachEvent(document,"touchstart",s.onDocumentTouchStart),s.attachEvent(window,"resize",s.onWindowResize)},init:function(){s.jscolor.lookupClass&&s.jscolor.installByClassName(s.jscolor.lookupClass)},tryInstallOnElements:function(e,t){for(var n=new RegExp("(^|\\s)("+t+")(\\s*(\\{[^}]*\\})|\\s|$)","i"),o=0;o<e.length;o+=1){var r;if(void 0===e[o].type||"color"!=e[o].type.toLowerCase()||!s.isColorAttrSupported)if(!e[o].jscolor&&e[o].className&&(r=e[o].className.match(n))){var i=e[o],l=null,a=s.getDataAttr(i,"jscolor");null!==a?l=a:r[4]&&(l=r[4]);var d={};if(l)try{d=new Function("return ("+l+")")()}catch(e){s.warn("Error parsing jscolor options: "+e+":\n"+l)}i.jscolor=new s.jscolor(i,d)}}},isColorAttrSupported:(i=document.createElement("input"),!(!i.setAttribute||(i.setAttribute("type","color"),"color"!=i.type.toLowerCase()))),isCanvasSupported:(r=document.createElement("canvas"),!(!r.getContext||!r.getContext("2d"))),fetchElement:function(e){return"string"==typeof e?document.getElementById(e):e},isElementType:function(e,t){return e.nodeName.toLowerCase()===t.toLowerCase()},getDataAttr:function(e,t){var n="data-"+t,o=e.getAttribute(n);return null!==o?o:null},attachEvent:function(e,t,n){e.addEventListener?e.addEventListener(t,n,!1):e.attachEvent&&e.attachEvent("on"+t,n)},detachEvent:function(e,t,n){e.removeEventListener?e.removeEventListener(t,n,!1):e.detachEvent&&e.detachEvent("on"+t,n)},_attachedGroupEvents:{},attachGroupEvent:function(e,t,n,o){s._attachedGroupEvents.hasOwnProperty(e)||(s._attachedGroupEvents[e]=[]),s._attachedGroupEvents[e].push([t,n,o]),s.attachEvent(t,n,o)},detachGroupEvents:function(e){if(s._attachedGroupEvents.hasOwnProperty(e)){for(var t=0;t<s._attachedGroupEvents[e].length;t+=1){var n=s._attachedGroupEvents[e][t];s.detachEvent(n[0],n[1],n[2])}delete s._attachedGroupEvents[e]}},attachDOMReadyEvent:function(e){var t=!1,n=function(){t||(t=!0,e())};if("complete"!==document.readyState){if(document.addEventListener)document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),window.addEventListener("load",n,!1);else if(document.attachEvent&&(document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===document.readyState&&(document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange",arguments.callee),n())}),window.attachEvent("onload",n),document.documentElement.doScroll&&window==window.top)){var o=function(){if(document.body)try{document.documentElement.doScroll("left"),n()}catch(e){setTimeout(o,1)}};o()}}else setTimeout(n,1)},warn:function(e){window.console&&window.console.warn&&window.console.warn(e)},preventDefault:function(e){e.preventDefault&&e.preventDefault(),e.returnValue=!1},captureTarget:function(e){e.setCapture&&(s._capturedTarget=e,s._capturedTarget.setCapture())},releaseTarget:function(){s._capturedTarget&&(s._capturedTarget.releaseCapture(),s._capturedTarget=null)},fireEvent:function(e,t){if(e)if(document.createEvent)(n=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")).initEvent(t,!0,!0),e.dispatchEvent(n);else if(document.createEventObject){var n=document.createEventObject();e.fireEvent("on"+t,n)}else e["on"+t]&&e["on"+t]()},classNameToList:function(e){return e.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s+/)},hasClass:function(e,t){return!!t&&-1!=(" "+e.className.replace(/\s+/g," ")+" ").indexOf(" "+t+" ")},setClass:function(e,t){for(var n=s.classNameToList(t),o=0;o<n.length;o+=1)s.hasClass(e,n[o])||(e.className+=(e.className?" ":"")+n[o])},unsetClass:function(e,t){for(var n=s.classNameToList(t),o=0;o<n.length;o+=1){var r=new RegExp("^\\s*"+n[o]+"\\s*|\\s*"+n[o]+"\\s*$|\\s+"+n[o]+"(\\s+)","g");e.className=e.className.replace(r,"$1")}},getStyle:function(e){return window.getComputedStyle?window.getComputedStyle(e):e.currentStyle},setStyle:(t=document.createElement("div"),n=function(e){for(var n=0;n<e.length;n+=1)if(e[n]in t.style)return e[n]},o={borderRadius:n(["borderRadius","MozBorderRadius","webkitBorderRadius"]),boxShadow:n(["boxShadow","MozBoxShadow","webkitBoxShadow"])},function(e,t,n){switch(t.toLowerCase()){case"opacity":var r=Math.round(100*parseFloat(n));e.style.opacity=n,e.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+r+")";break;default:e.style[o[t]]=n}}),setBorderRadius:function(e,t){s.setStyle(e,"borderRadius",t||"0")},setBoxShadow:function(e,t){s.setStyle(e,"boxShadow",t||"none")},getElementPos:function(e,t){var n=0,o=0,r=e.getBoundingClientRect();if(n=r.left,o=r.top,!t){var i=s.getViewPos();n+=i[0],o+=i[1]}return[n,o]},getElementSize:function(e){return[e.offsetWidth,e.offsetHeight]},getAbsPointerPos:function(e){e||(e=window.event);var t=0,n=0;return void 0!==e.changedTouches&&e.changedTouches.length?(t=e.changedTouches[0].clientX,n=e.changedTouches[0].clientY):"number"==typeof e.clientX&&(t=e.clientX,n=e.clientY),{x:t,y:n}},getRelPointerPos:function(e){e||(e=window.event);var t=(e.target||e.srcElement).getBoundingClientRect(),n=0,o=0;return void 0!==e.changedTouches&&e.changedTouches.length?(n=e.changedTouches[0].clientX,o=e.changedTouches[0].clientY):"number"==typeof e.clientX&&(n=e.clientX,o=e.clientY),{x:n-t.left,y:o-t.top}},getViewPos:function(){var e=document.documentElement;return[(window.pageXOffset||e.scrollLeft)-(e.clientLeft||0),(window.pageYOffset||e.scrollTop)-(e.clientTop||0)]},getViewSize:function(){var e=document.documentElement;return[window.innerWidth||e.clientWidth,window.innerHeight||e.clientHeight]},redrawPosition:function(){if(s.picker&&s.picker.owner){var e,t,n=s.picker.owner;n.fixed?(e=s.getElementPos(n.targetElement,!0),t=[0,0]):(e=s.getElementPos(n.targetElement),t=s.getViewPos());var o,r,i,l=s.getElementSize(n.targetElement),a=s.getViewSize(),d=s.getPickerOuterDims(n);switch(n.position.toLowerCase()){case"left":o=1,r=0,i=-1;break;case"right":o=1,r=0,i=1;break;case"top":o=0,r=1,i=-1;break;default:o=0,r=1,i=1}var c=(l[r]+d[r])/2;if(n.smartPosition)h=[-t[o]+e[o]+d[o]>a[o]&&-t[o]+e[o]+l[o]/2>a[o]/2&&e[o]+l[o]-d[o]>=0?e[o]+l[o]-d[o]:e[o],-t[r]+e[r]+l[r]+d[r]-c+c*i>a[r]?-t[r]+e[r]+l[r]/2>a[r]/2&&e[r]+l[r]-c-c*i>=0?e[r]+l[r]-c-c*i:e[r]+l[r]-c+c*i:e[r]+l[r]-c+c*i>=0?e[r]+l[r]-c+c*i:e[r]+l[r]-c-c*i];else var h=[e[o],e[r]+l[r]-c+c*i];var p=h[o],u=h[r],m=n.fixed?"fixed":"absolute",v=(h[0]+d[0]>e[0]||h[0]<e[0]+l[0])&&h[1]+d[1]<e[1]+l[1];s._drawPosition(n,p,u,m,v)}},_drawPosition:function(e,t,n,o,r){var i=r?0:e.shadowBlur;s.picker.wrap.style.position=o,s.picker.wrap.style.left=t+"px",s.picker.wrap.style.top=n+"px",s.setBoxShadow(s.picker.boxS,e.shadow?new s.BoxShadow(0,i,e.shadowBlur,0,e.shadowColor):null)},getPickerDims:function(e){var t=!!s.getSliderComponent(e);return[2*e.insetWidth+2*e.padding+e.width+(t?2*e.insetWidth+s.getPadToSliderPadding(e)+e.sliderSize:0),2*e.insetWidth+2*e.padding+e.height+(e.closable?2*e.insetWidth+e.padding+e.buttonHeight:0)]},getPickerOuterDims:function(e){var t=s.getPickerDims(e);return[t[0]+2*e.borderWidth,t[1]+2*e.borderWidth]},getPadToSliderPadding:function(e){return Math.max(e.padding,1.5*(2*e.pointerBorderWidth+e.pointerThickness))},getPadYComponent:function(e){switch(e.mode.charAt(1).toLowerCase()){case"v":return"v"}return"s"},getSliderComponent:function(e){if(e.mode.length>2)switch(e.mode.charAt(2).toLowerCase()){case"s":return"s";case"v":return"v"}return null},onDocumentMouseDown:function(e){e||(e=window.event);var t=e.target||e.srcElement;t._jscLinkedInstance?t._jscLinkedInstance.showOnClick&&t._jscLinkedInstance.show():t._jscControlName?s.onControlPointerStart(e,t,t._jscControlName,"mouse"):s.picker&&s.picker.owner&&s.picker.owner.hide()},onDocumentTouchStart:function(e){e||(e=window.event);var t=e.target||e.srcElement;t._jscLinkedInstance?t._jscLinkedInstance.showOnClick&&t._jscLinkedInstance.show():t._jscControlName?s.onControlPointerStart(e,t,t._jscControlName,"touch"):s.picker&&s.picker.owner&&s.picker.owner.hide()},onWindowResize:function(e){s.redrawPosition()},onParentScroll:function(e){s.picker&&s.picker.owner&&s.picker.owner.hide()},_pointerMoveEvent:{mouse:"mousemove",touch:"touchmove"},_pointerEndEvent:{mouse:"mouseup",touch:"touchend"},_pointerOrigin:null,_capturedTarget:null,onControlPointerStart:function(e,t,n,o){var r=t._jscInstance;s.preventDefault(e),s.captureTarget(t);var i=function(r,i){s.attachGroupEvent("drag",r,s._pointerMoveEvent[o],s.onDocumentPointerMove(e,t,n,o,i)),s.attachGroupEvent("drag",r,s._pointerEndEvent[o],s.onDocumentPointerEnd(e,t,n,o))};if(i(document,[0,0]),window.parent&&window.frameElement){var l=window.frameElement.getBoundingClientRect(),a=[-l.left,-l.top];i(window.parent.window.document,a)}var d=s.getAbsPointerPos(e),c=s.getRelPointerPos(e);switch(s._pointerOrigin={x:d.x-c.x,y:d.y-c.y},n){case"pad":switch(s.getSliderComponent(r)){case"s":0===r.hsv[1]&&r.fromHSV(null,100,null);break;case"v":0===r.hsv[2]&&r.fromHSV(null,null,100)}s.setPad(r,e,0,0);break;case"sld":s.setSld(r,e,0)}s.dispatchFineChange(r)},onDocumentPointerMove:function(e,t,n,o,r){return function(e){var o=t._jscInstance;switch(n){case"pad":e||(e=window.event),s.setPad(o,e,r[0],r[1]),s.dispatchFineChange(o);break;case"sld":e||(e=window.event),s.setSld(o,e,r[1]),s.dispatchFineChange(o)}}},onDocumentPointerEnd:function(e,t,n,o){return function(e){var n=t._jscInstance;s.detachGroupEvents("drag"),s.releaseTarget(),s.dispatchChange(n)}},dispatchChange:function(e){e.valueElement&&s.isElementType(e.valueElement,"input")&&s.fireEvent(e.valueElement,"change")},dispatchFineChange:function(e){e.onFineChange&&("string"==typeof e.onFineChange?new Function(e.onFineChange):e.onFineChange).call(e)},setPad:function(e,t,n,o){var r=s.getAbsPointerPos(t),i=n+r.x-s._pointerOrigin.x-e.padding-e.insetWidth,l=o+r.y-s._pointerOrigin.y-e.padding-e.insetWidth,a=i*(360/(e.width-1)),d=100-l*(100/(e.height-1));switch(s.getPadYComponent(e)){case"s":e.fromHSV(a,d,null,s.leaveSld);break;case"v":e.fromHSV(a,null,d,s.leaveSld)}},setSld:function(e,t,n){var o=100-(n+s.getAbsPointerPos(t).y-s._pointerOrigin.y-e.padding-e.insetWidth)*(100/(e.height-1));switch(s.getSliderComponent(e)){case"s":e.fromHSV(null,o,null,s.leavePad);break;case"v":e.fromHSV(null,null,o,s.leavePad)}},_vmlNS:"jsc_vml_",_vmlCSS:"jsc_vml_css_",_vmlReady:!1,initVML:function(){if(!s._vmlReady){var e=document;if(e.namespaces[s._vmlNS]||e.namespaces.add(s._vmlNS,"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"),!e.styleSheets[s._vmlCSS]){var t=["shape","shapetype","group","background","path","formulas","handles","fill","stroke","shadow","textbox","textpath","imagedata","line","polyline","curve","rect","roundrect","oval","arc","image"],n=e.createStyleSheet();n.owningElement.id=s._vmlCSS;for(var o=0;o<t.length;o+=1)n.addRule(s._vmlNS+"\\:"+t[o],"behavior:url(#default#VML);")}s._vmlReady=!0}},createPalette:function(){var e={elm:null,draw:null};if(s.isCanvasSupported){var t=document.createElement("canvas"),n=t.getContext("2d"),o=function(e,o,r){t.width=e,t.height=o,n.clearRect(0,0,t.width,t.height);var i=n.createLinearGradient(0,0,t.width,0);i.addColorStop(0,"#F00"),i.addColorStop(1/6,"#FF0"),i.addColorStop(2/6,"#0F0"),i.addColorStop(.5,"#0FF"),i.addColorStop(4/6,"#00F"),i.addColorStop(5/6,"#F0F"),i.addColorStop(1,"#F00"),n.fillStyle=i,n.fillRect(0,0,t.width,t.height);var s=n.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,t.height);switch(r.toLowerCase()){case"s":s.addColorStop(0,"rgba(255,255,255,0)"),s.addColorStop(1,"rgba(255,255,255,1)");break;case"v":s.addColorStop(0,"rgba(0,0,0,0)"),s.addColorStop(1,"rgba(0,0,0,1)")}n.fillStyle=s,n.fillRect(0,0,t.width,t.height)};e.elm=t,e.draw=o}else{s.initVML();var r=document.createElement("div");r.style.position="relative",r.style.overflow="hidden";var i=document.createElement(s._vmlNS+":fill");i.type="gradient",i.method="linear",i.angle="90",i.colors="16.67% #F0F, 33.33% #00F, 50% #0FF, 66.67% #0F0, 83.33% #FF0";var l=document.createElement(s._vmlNS+":rect");l.style.position="absolute",l.style.left="-1px",l.style.top="-1px",l.stroked=!1,l.appendChild(i),r.appendChild(l);var a=document.createElement(s._vmlNS+":fill");a.type="gradient",a.method="linear",a.angle="180",a.opacity="0";var d=document.createElement(s._vmlNS+":rect");d.style.position="absolute",d.style.left="-1px",d.style.top="-1px",d.stroked=!1,d.appendChild(a),r.appendChild(d);o=function(e,t,n){switch(r.style.width=e+"px",r.style.height=t+"px",l.style.width=d.style.width=e+1+"px",l.style.height=d.style.height=t+1+"px",i.color="#F00",i.color2="#F00",n.toLowerCase()){case"s":a.color=a.color2="#FFF";break;case"v":a.color=a.color2="#000"}};e.elm=r,e.draw=o}return e},createSliderGradient:function(){var e={elm:null,draw:null};if(s.isCanvasSupported){var t=document.createElement("canvas"),n=t.getContext("2d"),o=function(e,o,r,i){t.width=e,t.height=o,n.clearRect(0,0,t.width,t.height);var s=n.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,t.height);s.addColorStop(0,r),s.addColorStop(1,i),n.fillStyle=s,n.fillRect(0,0,t.width,t.height)};e.elm=t,e.draw=o}else{s.initVML();var r=document.createElement("div");r.style.position="relative",r.style.overflow="hidden";var i=document.createElement(s._vmlNS+":fill");i.type="gradient",i.method="linear",i.angle="180";var l=document.createElement(s._vmlNS+":rect");l.style.position="absolute",l.style.left="-1px",l.style.top="-1px",l.stroked=!1,l.appendChild(i),r.appendChild(l);o=function(e,t,n,o){r.style.width=e+"px",r.style.height=t+"px",l.style.width=e+1+"px",l.style.height=t+1+"px",i.color=n,i.color2=o};e.elm=r,e.draw=o}return e},leaveValue:1,leaveStyle:2,leavePad:4,leaveSld:8,BoxShadow:(e=function(e,t,n,o,r,i){this.hShadow=e,this.vShadow=t,this.blur=n,this.spread=o,this.color=r,this.inset=!!i},e.prototype.toString=function(){var e=[Math.round(this.hShadow)+"px",Math.round(this.vShadow)+"px",Math.round(this.blur)+"px",Math.round(this.spread)+"px",this.color];return this.inset&&e.push("inset"),e.join(" ")},e),jscolor:function(e,t){for(var n in this.value=null,this.valueElement=e,this.styleElement=e,this.required=!0,this.refine=!0,this.hash=!1,this.uppercase=!0,this.onFineChange=null,this.activeClass="jscolor-active",this.minS=0,this.maxS=100,this.minV=0,this.maxV=100,this.hsv=[0,0,100],this.rgb=[255,255,255],this.width=181,this.height=101,this.showOnClick=!0,this.mode="HSV",this.position="bottom",this.smartPosition=!0,this.sliderSize=16,this.crossSize=8,this.closable=!1,this.closeText="Close",this.buttonColor="#000000",this.buttonHeight=18,this.padding=12,this.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF",this.borderWidth=1,this.borderColor="#BBBBBB",this.borderRadius=8,this.insetWidth=1,this.insetColor="#BBBBBB",this.shadow=!0,this.shadowBlur=15,this.shadowColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",this.pointerColor="#4C4C4C",this.pointerBorderColor="#FFFFFF",this.pointerBorderWidth=1,this.pointerThickness=2,this.zIndex=1e3,this.container=null,t)t.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(this[n]=t[n]);function o(e,t,n){var o=n/100*255;if(null===e)return[o,o,o];e/=60,t/=100;var r=Math.floor(e),i=o*(1-t),s=o*(1-t*(r%2?e-r:1-(e-r)));switch(r){case 6:case 0:return[o,s,i];case 1:return[s,o,i];case 2:return[i,o,s];case 3:return[i,s,o];case 4:return[s,i,o];case 5:return[o,i,s]}}function r(){h._processParentElementsInDOM(),s.picker||(s.picker={owner:null,wrap:document.createElement("div"),box:document.createElement("div"),boxS:document.createElement("div"),boxB:document.createElement("div"),pad:document.createElement("div"),padB:document.createElement("div"),padM:document.createElement("div"),padPal:s.createPalette(),cross:document.createElement("div"),crossBY:document.createElement("div"),crossBX:document.createElement("div"),crossLY:document.createElement("div"),crossLX:document.createElement("div"),sld:document.createElement("div"),sldB:document.createElement("div"),sldM:document.createElement("div"),sldGrad:s.createSliderGradient(),sldPtrS:document.createElement("div"),sldPtrIB:document.createElement("div"),sldPtrMB:document.createElement("div"),sldPtrOB:document.createElement("div"),btn:document.createElement("div"),btnT:document.createElement("span")},s.picker.pad.appendChild(s.picker.padPal.elm),s.picker.padB.appendChild(s.picker.pad),s.picker.cross.appendChild(s.picker.crossBY),s.picker.cross.appendChild(s.picker.crossBX),s.picker.cross.appendChild(s.picker.crossLY),s.picker.cross.appendChild(s.picker.crossLX),s.picker.padB.appendChild(s.picker.cross),s.picker.box.appendChild(s.picker.padB),s.picker.box.appendChild(s.picker.padM),s.picker.sld.appendChild(s.picker.sldGrad.elm),s.picker.sldB.appendChild(s.picker.sld),s.picker.sldB.appendChild(s.picker.sldPtrOB),s.picker.sldPtrOB.appendChild(s.picker.sldPtrMB),s.picker.sldPtrMB.appendChild(s.picker.sldPtrIB),s.picker.sldPtrIB.appendChild(s.picker.sldPtrS),s.picker.box.appendChild(s.picker.sldB),s.picker.box.appendChild(s.picker.sldM),s.picker.btn.appendChild(s.picker.btnT),s.picker.box.appendChild(s.picker.btn),s.picker.boxB.appendChild(s.picker.box),s.picker.wrap.appendChild(s.picker.boxS),s.picker.wrap.appendChild(s.picker.boxB));var e,t,n=s.picker,o=!!s.getSliderComponent(h),r=s.getPickerDims(h),a=2*h.pointerBorderWidth+h.pointerThickness+2*h.crossSize,d=s.getPadToSliderPadding(h),c=Math.min(h.borderRadius,Math.round(h.padding*Math.PI));n.wrap.style.clear="both",n.wrap.style.width=r[0]+2*h.borderWidth+"px",n.wrap.style.height=r[1]+2*h.borderWidth+"px",n.wrap.style.zIndex=h.zIndex,n.box.style.width=r[0]+"px",n.box.style.height=r[1]+"px",n.boxS.style.position="absolute",n.boxS.style.left="0",n.boxS.style.top="0",n.boxS.style.width="100%",n.boxS.style.height="100%",s.setBorderRadius(n.boxS,c+"px"),n.boxB.style.position="relative",n.boxB.style.border=h.borderWidth+"px solid",n.boxB.style.borderColor=h.borderColor,n.boxB.style.background=h.backgroundColor,s.setBorderRadius(n.boxB,c+"px"),n.padM.style.background=n.sldM.style.background="#FFF",s.setStyle(n.padM,"opacity","0"),s.setStyle(n.sldM,"opacity","0"),n.pad.style.position="relative",n.pad.style.width=h.width+"px",n.pad.style.height=h.height+"px",n.padPal.draw(h.width,h.height,s.getPadYComponent(h)),n.padB.style.position="absolute",n.padB.style.left=h.padding+"px",n.padB.style.top=h.padding+"px",n.padB.style.border=h.insetWidth+"px solid",n.padB.style.borderColor=h.insetColor,n.padM._jscInstance=h,n.padM._jscControlName="pad",n.padM.style.position="absolute",n.padM.style.left="0",n.padM.style.top="0",n.padM.style.width=h.padding+2*h.insetWidth+h.width+d/2+"px",n.padM.style.height=r[1]+"px",n.padM.style.cursor="crosshair",n.cross.style.position="absolute",n.cross.style.left=n.cross.style.top="0",n.cross.style.width=n.cross.style.height=a+"px",n.crossBY.style.position=n.crossBX.style.position="absolute",n.crossBY.style.background=n.crossBX.style.background=h.pointerBorderColor,n.crossBY.style.width=n.crossBX.style.height=2*h.pointerBorderWidth+h.pointerThickness+"px",n.crossBY.style.height=n.crossBX.style.width=a+"px",n.crossBY.style.left=n.crossBX.style.top=Math.floor(a/2)-Math.floor(h.pointerThickness/2)-h.pointerBorderWidth+"px",n.crossBY.style.top=n.crossBX.style.left="0",n.crossLY.style.position=n.crossLX.style.position="absolute",n.crossLY.style.background=n.crossLX.style.background=h.pointerColor,n.crossLY.style.height=n.crossLX.style.width=a-2*h.pointerBorderWidth+"px",n.crossLY.style.width=n.crossLX.style.height=h.pointerThickness+"px",n.crossLY.style.left=n.crossLX.style.top=Math.floor(a/2)-Math.floor(h.pointerThickness/2)+"px",n.crossLY.style.top=n.crossLX.style.left=h.pointerBorderWidth+"px",n.sld.style.overflow="hidden",n.sld.style.width=h.sliderSize+"px",n.sld.style.height=h.height+"px",n.sldGrad.draw(h.sliderSize,h.height,"#000","#000"),n.sldB.style.display=o?"block":"none",n.sldB.style.position="absolute",n.sldB.style.right=h.padding+"px",n.sldB.style.top=h.padding+"px",n.sldB.style.border=h.insetWidth+"px solid",n.sldB.style.borderColor=h.insetColor,n.sldM._jscInstance=h,n.sldM._jscControlName="sld",n.sldM.style.display=o?"block":"none",n.sldM.style.position="absolute",n.sldM.style.right="0",n.sldM.style.top="0",n.sldM.style.width=h.sliderSize+d/2+h.padding+2*h.insetWidth+"px",n.sldM.style.height=r[1]+"px",n.sldM.style.cursor="default",n.sldPtrIB.style.border=n.sldPtrOB.style.border=h.pointerBorderWidth+"px solid "+h.pointerBorderColor,n.sldPtrOB.style.position="absolute",n.sldPtrOB.style.left=-(2*h.pointerBorderWidth+h.pointerThickness)+"px",n.sldPtrOB.style.top="0",n.sldPtrMB.style.border=h.pointerThickness+"px solid "+h.pointerColor,n.sldPtrS.style.width=h.sliderSize+"px",n.sldPtrS.style.height=u+"px",n.btn.style.display=h.closable?"block":"none",n.btn.style.position="absolute",n.btn.style.left=h.padding+"px",n.btn.style.bottom=h.padding+"px",n.btn.style.padding="0 15px",n.btn.style.height=h.buttonHeight+"px",n.btn.style.border=h.insetWidth+"px solid",e=h.insetColor.split(/\s+/),t=e.length<2?e[0]:e[1]+" "+e[0]+" "+e[0]+" "+e[1],n.btn.style.borderColor=t,n.btn.style.color=h.buttonColor,n.btn.style.font="12px sans-serif",n.btn.style.textAlign="center";try{n.btn.style.cursor="pointer"}catch(e){n.btn.style.cursor="hand"}n.btn.onmousedown=function(){h.hide()},n.btnT.style.lineHeight=h.buttonHeight+"px",n.btnT.innerHTML="",n.btnT.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h.closeText)),i(),l(),s.picker.owner&&s.picker.owner!==h&&s.unsetClass(s.picker.owner.targetElement,h.activeClass),s.picker.owner=h,s.isElementType(p,"body")?s.redrawPosition():s._drawPosition(h,0,0,"relative",!1),n.wrap.parentNode!=p&&p.appendChild(n.wrap),s.setClass(h.targetElement,h.activeClass)}function i(){switch(s.getPadYComponent(h)){case"s":var e=1;break;case"v":e=2}var t=Math.round(h.hsv[0]/360*(h.width-1)),n=Math.round((1-h.hsv[e]/100)*(h.height-1)),r=2*h.pointerBorderWidth+h.pointerThickness+2*h.crossSize,i=-Math.floor(r/2);switch(s.picker.cross.style.left=t+i+"px",s.picker.cross.style.top=n+i+"px",s.getSliderComponent(h)){case"s":var l=o(h.hsv[0],100,h.hsv[2]),a=o(h.hsv[0],0,h.hsv[2]),d="rgb("+Math.round(l[0])+","+Math.round(l[1])+","+Math.round(l[2])+")",c="rgb("+Math.round(a[0])+","+Math.round(a[1])+","+Math.round(a[2])+")";s.picker.sldGrad.draw(h.sliderSize,h.height,d,c);break;case"v":var p=o(h.hsv[0],h.hsv[1],100);d="rgb("+Math.round(p[0])+","+Math.round(p[1])+","+Math.round(p[2])+")",c="#000";s.picker.sldGrad.draw(h.sliderSize,h.height,d,c)}}function l(){var e=s.getSliderComponent(h);if(e){switch(e){case"s":var t=1;break;case"v":t=2}var n=Math.round((1-h.hsv[t]/100)*(h.height-1));s.picker.sldPtrOB.style.top=n-(2*h.pointerBorderWidth+h.pointerThickness)-Math.floor(u/2)+"px"}}function a(){return s.picker&&s.picker.owner===h}if(this.hide=function(){a()&&(s.unsetClass(h.targetElement,h.activeClass),s.picker.wrap.parentNode.removeChild(s.picker.wrap),delete s.picker.owner)},this.show=function(){r()},this.redraw=function(){a()&&r()},this.importColor=function(){this.valueElement&&s.isElementType(this.valueElement,"input")?this.refine?!this.required&&/^\s*$/.test(this.valueElement.value)?(this.valueElement.value="",this.styleElement&&(this.styleElement.style.backgroundImage=this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle.backgroundImage,this.styleElement.style.backgroundColor=this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle.backgroundColor,this.styleElement.style.color=this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle.color),this.exportColor(s.leaveValue|s.leaveStyle)):this.fromString(this.valueElement.value)||this.exportColor():this.fromString(this.valueElement.value,s.leaveValue)||(this.styleElement&&(this.styleElement.style.backgroundImage=this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle.backgroundImage,this.styleElement.style.backgroundColor=this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle.backgroundColor,this.styleElement.style.color=this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle.color),this.exportColor(s.leaveValue|s.leaveStyle)):this.exportColor()},this.exportColor=function(e){if(!(e&s.leaveValue)&&this.valueElement){var t=this.toString();this.uppercase&&(t=t.toUpperCase()),this.hash&&(t="#"+t),s.isElementType(this.valueElement,"input")?this.valueElement.value=t:this.valueElement.innerHTML=t}e&s.leaveStyle||this.styleElement&&(this.styleElement.style.backgroundImage="none",this.styleElement.style.backgroundColor="#"+this.toString(),this.styleElement.style.color=this.isLight()?"#000":"#FFF"),e&s.leavePad||!a()||i(),e&s.leaveSld||!a()||l()},this.fromHSV=function(e,t,n,r){if(null!==e){if(isNaN(e))return!1;e=Math.max(0,Math.min(360,e))}if(null!==t){if(isNaN(t))return!1;t=Math.max(0,Math.min(100,this.maxS,t),this.minS)}if(null!==n){if(isNaN(n))return!1;n=Math.max(0,Math.min(100,this.maxV,n),this.minV)}this.rgb=o(null===e?this.hsv[0]:this.hsv[0]=e,null===t?this.hsv[1]:this.hsv[1]=t,null===n?this.hsv[2]:this.hsv[2]=n),this.exportColor(r)},this.fromRGB=function(e,t,n,r){if(null!==e){if(isNaN(e))return!1;e=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,e))}if(null!==t){if(isNaN(t))return!1;t=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,t))}if(null!==n){if(isNaN(n))return!1;n=Math.max(0,Math.min(255,n))}var i=function(e,t,n){e/=255,t/=255,n/=255;var o=Math.min(Math.min(e,t),n),r=Math.max(Math.max(e,t),n),i=r-o;if(0===i)return[null,0,100*r];var s=e===o?3+(n-t)/i:t===o?5+(e-n)/i:1+(t-e)/i;return[60*(6===s?0:s),i/r*100,100*r]}(null===e?this.rgb[0]:e,null===t?this.rgb[1]:t,null===n?this.rgb[2]:n);null!==i[0]&&(this.hsv[0]=Math.max(0,Math.min(360,i[0]))),0!==i[2]&&(this.hsv[1]=null===i[1]?null:Math.max(0,this.minS,Math.min(100,this.maxS,i[1]))),this.hsv[2]=null===i[2]?null:Math.max(0,this.minV,Math.min(100,this.maxV,i[2]));var s=o(this.hsv[0],this.hsv[1],this.hsv[2]);this.rgb[0]=s[0],this.rgb[1]=s[1],this.rgb[2]=s[2],this.exportColor(r)},this.fromString=function(e,t){var n;if(n=e.match(/^\W*([0-9A-F]{3}([0-9A-F]{3})?)\W*$/i))return 6===n[1].length?this.fromRGB(parseInt(n[1].substr(0,2),16),parseInt(n[1].substr(2,2),16),parseInt(n[1].substr(4,2),16),t):this.fromRGB(parseInt(n[1].charAt(0)+n[1].charAt(0),16),parseInt(n[1].charAt(1)+n[1].charAt(1),16),parseInt(n[1].charAt(2)+n[1].charAt(2),16),t),!0;if(n=e.match(/^\W*rgba?\(([^)]*)\)\W*$/i)){var o,r,i,s=n[1].split(","),l=/^\s*(\d*)(\.\d+)?\s*$/;if(s.length>=3&&(o=s[0].match(l))&&(r=s[1].match(l))&&(i=s[2].match(l))){var a=parseFloat((o[1]||"0")+(o[2]||"")),d=parseFloat((r[1]||"0")+(r[2]||"")),c=parseFloat((i[1]||"0")+(i[2]||""));return this.fromRGB(a,d,c,t),!0}}return!1},this.toString=function(){return(256|Math.round(this.rgb[0])).toString(16).substr(1)+(256|Math.round(this.rgb[1])).toString(16).substr(1)+(256|Math.round(this.rgb[2])).toString(16).substr(1)},this.toHEXString=function(){return"#"+this.toString().toUpperCase()},this.toRGBString=function(){return"rgb("+Math.round(this.rgb[0])+","+Math.round(this.rgb[1])+","+Math.round(this.rgb[2])+")"},this.isLight=function(){return.213*this.rgb[0]+.715*this.rgb[1]+.072*this.rgb[2]>127.5},this._processParentElementsInDOM=function(){if(!this._linkedElementsProcessed){this._linkedElementsProcessed=!0;var e=this.targetElement;do{var t=s.getStyle(e);t&&"fixed"===t.position.toLowerCase()&&(this.fixed=!0),e!==this.targetElement&&(e._jscEventsAttached||(s.attachEvent(e,"scroll",s.onParentScroll),e._jscEventsAttached=!0))}while((e=e.parentNode)&&!s.isElementType(e,"body"))}},"string"==typeof e){var d=e,c=document.getElementById(d);c?this.targetElement=c:s.warn("Could not find target element with ID '"+d+"'")}else e?this.targetElement=e:s.warn("Invalid target element: '"+e+"'");if(this.targetElement._jscLinkedInstance)s.warn("Cannot link jscolor twice to the same element. Skipping.");else{this.targetElement._jscLinkedInstance=this,this.valueElement=s.fetchElement(this.valueElement),this.styleElement=s.fetchElement(this.styleElement);var h=this,p=this.container?s.fetchElement(this.container):document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],u=3;if(s.isElementType(this.targetElement,"button"))if(this.targetElement.onclick){var m=this.targetElement.onclick;this.targetElement.onclick=function(e){return m.call(this,e),!1}}else this.targetElement.onclick=function(){return!1};if(this.valueElement&&s.isElementType(this.valueElement,"input")){var v=function(){h.fromString(h.valueElement.value,s.leaveValue),s.dispatchFineChange(h)};s.attachEvent(this.valueElement,"keyup",v),s.attachEvent(this.valueElement,"input",v),s.attachEvent(this.valueElement,"blur",function(){h.importColor()}),this.valueElement.setAttribute("autocomplete","off")}this.styleElement&&(this.styleElement._jscOrigStyle={backgroundImage:this.styleElement.style.backgroundImage,backgroundColor:this.styleElement.style.backgroundColor,color:this.styleElement.style.color}),this.value?this.fromString(this.value)||this.exportColor():this.importColor()}}};return s.jscolor.lookupClass="jscolor",s.jscolor.installByClassName=function(e){var t=document.getElementsByTagName("input"),n=document.getElementsByTagName("button");s.tryInstallOnElements(t,e),s.tryInstallOnElements(n,e)},s.register(),s.jscolor}());
```

```css
.miti{border:1px solid gray;width:20%;display:inline-flex;flex-flow:column wrap;justify-content:center;padding:30px;align-items:center}#rect,.rounded{display:inline-block}#rect{border:1px solid green;width:100%;height:100px;background-color:#eee;margin:12px 0}.border,.rounded{height:100px;width:100px}.rounded{background-color:red;border-radius:50%}.border,p{display:block}.border{border:3px solid red}p{color:red}
```

```html
<div class="miti">
  <p>Rectangle color:
    <input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">
    <span id="rect"></span>
</div>
<div class="miti">
  <div class="rounded"></div>
  <p>Texto pintado</p>
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿En dónde debería resetear el color, en el círculo, en el cuadrado o dónde?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que si cambias el color picker a amarillo por ejemplo se cambie el circulo, los textos y el rectangulo a amarillo?

Comment: Cuando seleccione el color, debería cambiar todo lo que tenga en su css el color rojo (red)

Comment: Te he colocado una solución vía **customproperties** de css, creo que aplica bastante a lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Cuando agregues código en tu pregunta, por favor formatealo en diferentes líneas de modo que sea legible!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo sugiero que hagas lo siguiente, usa **custom-properties** en css y guarda el color en variables así:

```
:root{
  --color: green;
}
```

En cada elemento, clase o id, usa sencillamente la variable indistamente de si es para fondo, color de letra o borde, así:

```
.class{
  background-color: var(--color);
  color: var(--color);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px var(--color) ;
  border-color: var(--color);
  /*etc*/
}
```

Y por javascript añades en el `<head>`, la etiqueta `<style>`, para sobreescribir la variable, de modo que quede:

```
<head>
  <style>
    body{ --color: colorInput ; }
  </style>
</head>
```

No soy experto en vanilla javascript, pero hice esta demo (que funciona) haciendo lo que te digo:

```js
var inputColor = document.getElementById('colorjs');
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';    

inputColor.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var theColor = inputColor.value;
  var css = 'body{ --color: '+theColor+';}';
  if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  } 
}) 

head.appendChild(style);
```

```css
:root{
--color: blue;
}

.miti {
  border:1px solid var(--color); 
  width:20%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}
#rect {
  border:1px solid var(--color); 
  width:100%; 
  height:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.rounded {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.border {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 3px;
  display: block;
}
p {
  display: block;
}

.color-bg { background-color: var(--color); }
.color-bo { border-color:var(--color); }
.color-co { color: var(--color); }
```

```html
<div class="miti">
  <p class="color-co">Rectangle color:
  <input id="colorjs" type="color" name="favcolor" value="#0000ff">
  <span id="rect"></span>
</div>
<div class="miti">
  <div class="rounded color-bg"></div>
  <p class="color-co">Texto pintado</p>
  <div class="border color-bo"></div>
</div>
```

En estos casos es muy útil usar las **custom-properties**, precisamente por el control que añade sobre propiedades css y cómo podemos manipularlas fácilmente desde js y [la mayoría de navegadores modernos la soportan](https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20prop).

Answer (score 2):

Hice una modificación en tu código.

Añadí clases nuevas a tu hoja de estilos y al html, para actuar sobre estas en javascript.

De esta manera, insertes los elementos que insertes en html, siempre que apliques alguna de estas clases en ellos, el elemento se verá afectado y cambiará de color también.

Espero te sirva.

https://codepen.io/zeross/pen/NYNbJg

**Edit:**

A petición popular, añado código a la respuesta.

```js
function update(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".red-bg, .red-co, .red-bo");
    elements.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.classList.contains('red-bg'))
        item.style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;
      if (item.classList.contains('red-co'))
        item.style.color = '#' + jscolor;
      if (item.classList.contains('red-bo'))
        item.style.borderColor = '#' + jscolor;
    });
}
```

```css
.miti {
  border:1px solid gray; 
  width:20%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}
#rect {
  border:1px solid green; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.rounded {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.border {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 3px;
  display: block;
}
p {
  display: block;
}

.red-bg { background-color: red; }
.red-bo { border-color:red; }
.red-co { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="miti">
      <p class="red-co">Rectangle color:
      <input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">
      <span id="rect"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="miti">
      <div class="rounded red-bg"></div>
      <p class="red-co">Texto pintado</p>
      <div class="border red-bo"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos, tu código esta muy bien, pero mi necesidad es que necesito afectar muchas clases que tienen un mismo color, en este caso #b71f37, entonces necesito un código que busque en mi hoja de estilos ese color y lo resetee por el nuevo, sin llamar a las clases que lo contienen si no la condición de color especifica. 

muchas gracias por el aporte

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código a tu respuesta? Luego de hacer click en [edit] selecciona el botón `< >` para incluir código HTML/JavaScript/CSS

Answer (score 1):

Con JavaScript puedes leer y modificar las reglas CSS usando [`cssRules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) y [`cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CSSRule/cssText). La idea sería leer las reglas con `cssRules` y entonces con expresiones regulares reemplazar las ocurrencias de "red" por el color escogido.

Aquí dejo una pequeña demo:

```js
function cambiarEstilos(color) {
  // obtenemos las reglas de CSS en una lista
  var clases = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
  // para cada una de ellas
  for (var x = 0; x < clases.length; x++) 
    // cambiamos el valor "red" por el valor seleccionado
    clases[x].style.cssText = clases[x].style.cssText.replace(/red/g, "#" + color)
}

function update(e) {
  document.getElementById("rect").style.backgroundColor = "#" + e;
  cambiarEstilos(e);
}
```

```css
.miti {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center
}

#rect,
.rounded {
  display: inline-block
}

#rect {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 12px 0
}

.border,
.rounded {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}

.rounded {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.border,
p {
  display: block
}

.border {
  border: 3px solid red
}

p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>

<div class="miti">
  <p>Rectangle color:
    <input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">
    <span id="rect"></span>
</div>
<div class="miti">
  <div class="rounded"></div>
  <p>Texto pintado</p>
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

---

Un problema de la versión anterior es que el valor está fijo a "red". Hacerlo dinámico y que cambie cada vez (teniendo "red" como valor por defecto) es algo más complejo porque el navegador cambia el valor de hexadecimal a RGB. Pero se puede hacer con la librería anterior sin muchos cambios.

Sería algo como esto:

```js
// por defecto el primer color será "red"
var colorViejo = "red";

function cambiarEstilos(color) {
  // creamos una expresión regular para detectar el color anterior
  var regex = new RegExp(colorViejo, "g");
  
  // obtenemos las reglas de CSS en una lista
  var clases = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
  // para cada una de ellas
  for (var x = 0; x < clases.length; x++)
    // cambiamos el valor anterior por el valor nuevo seleccionado en RGB
    clases[x].style.cssText = clases[x].style.cssText.replace(regex, color.toRGBString());

  // guardamos el color viejo en RGB (con algunos cambios porque el navegador es graciosete y cambia el valor)
  colorViejo = color.toRGBString().replace("(","\\(").replace(")","\\)").replace(/,/g,",\\s*");
}

function update(e) {
  document.getElementById("rect").style.backgroundColor = "#" + e;
  //console.log(e);
  cambiarEstilos(e);
}
```

```css
.miti {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center
}

#rect,
.rounded {
  display: inline-block
}

#rect {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 12px 0
}

.border,
.rounded {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}

.rounded {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.border,
p {
  display: block
}

.border {
  border: 3px solid red
}

p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>

<div class="miti">
  <p>Rectangle color:
    <input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">
    <span id="rect"></span>
</div>
<div class="miti">
  <div class="rounded"></div>
  <p>Texto pintado</p>
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pondría una explicación más larga, pero el problema es que el código que pones ocupa demasiado y no deja espacio para mucho más. Si es una biblioteca, dime el nombre para que el código se pueda reducir y añadirte una mejor explicación de qué hace y cómo funciona mi script.

Comment: Esta es la única que responde realmente a la pregunta... Hay algunos puntos a considerar: el regex no coincidiría con `Red`, traería problemas con `url(predef.png)` o cualquier propiedad que incluya a `red` en el nombre (si existiera), así como también reemplazaría a `darkred` por `dark#ffffff`... En cuanto a la función de reemplazo, también recomendaría [escapar los metacaracteres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49210/127).

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar LESS para la compilación de tu hoja de estilo del lado del cliente.

Acá tenes mas informacion de como compilar hojas de estilos mediante javascript.
http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage

El código debería ser mas o menos asi:

```
function update(jscolor) { less.modifyVars({ '@mivariableless': jscolor }); }
```